# Apply Groupby in EF with suitable results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, group-by

I am not much familiar with EF. I want to group rows based on IDs. I acheive this in SQL but I am getting some Issues with group by while implementeing in EF.

```
public ActionResult PropertyListing()
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Property");
            }
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetSpurts()
        {

            PropertySpurts property;
            List<PropertySpurts> listProperty = new List<PropertySpurts>();
            var userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"].ToString());
           // IEnumerable<tblPropertyView> PropertyList;

          var  PropertyList = from p in dbEntity.tblPropertyViews
                             join c in dbEntity.tblProperties on p.PropertyID equals c.ID into j1
                             from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()

                             group j2 by p.PropertyID into grouped
                             select new { ParentId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count(t => t.ID != null) };


            if (PropertyList != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in PropertyList)
                {
                    property = new PropertySpurts();

                    property.ID = (int)item.ParentId;
                    property.Title = item.tblProperty.Title;

                    listProperty.Add(property);
                }
            }

            return Json(listProperty, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

PropertyID in tblPropertyView is Foreign Key to tblProperty ID. I want to get title of Property from tblProperty. Please help me to find Title and Count of PropertyViews

TIA

[SOLVED]

```
var PropertyList = from p in dbEntity.tblPropertyViews
                               join c in dbEntity.tblProperties on p.PropertyID equals c.ID into j1
                               from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()

                               group j2 by new
                               {
                                   p.PropertyID,
                                   p.tblProperty.Title
                               } into grouped 
                               select new
                               {
                                   ParentId = grouped.Key.PropertyID,
                                   Title = grouped.Key.Title,
                                   Count = grouped.Count(t => t.ID != null)
                               };
```

This solves my issue. But I want this should be **orderby** count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var PropertyList = (from p in dbEntity.tblPropertyViews
                               join c in dbEntity.tblProperties on p.PropertyID equals c.ID into j1
                               from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()

                               group j2 by new
                               {
                                   p.PropertyID,
                                   p.tblProperty.Title
                               } into grouped 
                               select new
                               {
                                   ParentId = grouped.Key.PropertyID,
                                   Title = grouped.Key.Title,
                                   Count = grouped.Count(t => t.ID != null)
                               }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

Comment: After implementing this , I got following error: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<AnonymousType#1>' because it is not a delegate type` and `The name 'c' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @MySardar: Tell me more about errors you get. So I can support better.